# Logging all echo statements in tcsh script

Tags: linux, shell, tcsh

I am using a big tcsh script and I want redirect all the output of echo statements both to a file and standard output. I can use a tee command to do that but I have a requirement such that I should run only the script without any other command and all the output should be redirected to both standard output and a file. Is there any way to do this ?

I have tried using script command but it is spawning a new shell. It is not possible for me to put tee command statements all over the program.

Comment: Why can't use `tee`?

Comment: It is a very big script and I felt that  adding tee statements is not an efficient way of logging the outputs